# How to have persistent variable in android module?

Tags: java, android, mobile, module, titanium

I'm planning to create a module whereby information was stored in a variable in my java codes. I've made a simple test app whereby a variable in my java code was incremented by 1 every time a button was pressed.
When I tested it out, no matter how many times I press, it returns 1, no increment at all.
My java code:

```
private static int counter = 0;

@Kroll.method
public int increment() {
    setIncrementProp(1);
    return counter;
}

@Kroll.setProperty
public void setIncrementProp(int value) {
    counter = counter + value;
}
```

My Javascript code:

```
var module = require("com.modulewhatever");

var testToast = Titanium.UI.createNotification({ message :module.increment().toString() });

var button = Titanium.UI.createButton({ title : "Test" });

button.addEventListener("click", function(e) { testToast.show(); });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of a feature called `SharedPreference` in Android.

```
SharedPreferences p = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

p.edit().putString("username", username).commit();
p.edit().putString("password", password).commit(); //SECURITY HAZARD: read below...
```

for retrieving values,

```
String username = p.getString("username", "");
String password = p.getString("password", "");
```

Comment: ya Beat me to posting this as my answer :p